# Starting a Validator, It works, but it's not very good

Tags: snapshot

Starting a Validator(https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start#configure-solana-cli)

curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"getHealth"}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32005,"message":"Node is behind by 6295 slots","data":{"numSlotsBehind":6295}},"id":1}

curl -s http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"getBlockHeight"}
' | jq .result
150161443

Every time the data is cleared and re run, Download the snapshot again, When 8899 port can be accessed, the node height is about 150, xxx, xxx, Node is behind by **>5000** slots, And then it gets bigger and bigger, Far from the main network.

It has been re run for dozens of times, and the synchronization node cannot catch up

who can help me

Hardware
cpu 24 cores / 48 threads
ram >300g
disk 5T
Networking >300 m/s

Comment: The networking may be the problem here, or the args passed to the validator may make it nonperformant. Please include your full command line for how you're starting the validator.